# Create Expert system consist if-else statements without/little programming

Tags: programming

I am trying to develop a logic to create an expert system for my master dissertation. My focus is more on developing the logic rather than implementation now. But to demonstrate, I have to implement as well. I am looking for software through which I can implement if-else statements with little or no coding.

Can someone Please give list of these software or if these type of software exist or not.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There *are* some programming systems that allow construction of software without actually typing in code such as "Blocks" which you can see/try on [trinket.io](https://trinket.io/blocks):

[image]

**But** such systems are intended to give an introduction to programming rather than for serious products and so don't usually support expert systems. *In the example above you can switch to seeing your code in python.*

[Expert Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system), on the other hand, need a lot more than If..Else constructs, in fact most these days use a probabilistic approach given this information there is the percentage chance of ... - they generally need a lot of code and include the capability to be "trained" and are only considered "Expert" once they have been trained see [Deep Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning).

That said the [Python](https://www.python.org/) programming language is reasonably easy for a beginner to start making progress in and has a number of resources available for constructing expert systems or experimenting in deep learning that make it possible to construct an expert system with very few lines of coding on your part.

- [SciKit Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) *Machine Learning in Python*
- [Keras](https://keras.io/) *Deep Learning library for Theano and TensorFlow*
- [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) *Open Source Computer Vision* includes modules for constructing such systems.
- [PyCLIPS](http://pyclips.sourceforge.net/web/) PyCLIPS is an extension module for the Python language that embeds full CLIPS functionality in Python applications.
- [Rulu](https://github.com/ubarkai/rulu) provides a Pythonic, declarative interface for building rule-based expert systems.
- [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) Deep Learning Framework *While Caffe itself isn’t a Python library, it does provide bindings into the Python programming language.*
- [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/) *building blocks for neural networks*
- [Lasagne](https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne) ***lightweight*** *library used to construct and train networks in Theano*
- [Blocks](https://github.com/mila-udem/blocks) *a different one* Blocks is a framework that helps you build neural network models on top of Theano.

Some examples in [Python](https://www.python.org/) as can be seen in the PyImageSearch blog:

- [LeNet - Convolutional Neural Network](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/25/convolutions-with-opencv-and-python/)
- [Convolutions with OpenCV and Python](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/25/convolutions-with-opencv-and-python/)